# Sigmoid Derivative using nd4j

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, numpy, nd4j

I perform sigmoid which works fine but sigmoidDerivative gives the same result as sigmoid in nd4j. What is the difference between `Transforms.sigmoidDerivative(x)` and `Transforms.sigmoidDerivative(x, true)`?

```
INDArray x = Nd4j.create(new double[] { 0.1812, 0.1235, 0.8466 });
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(Transforms.sigmoid(x));
System.out.println(Transforms.sigmoidDerivative(x));
System.out.println(Transforms.sigmoidDerivative(x, true));
```

Gives output:

```
[[    0.1812,    0.1235,    0.8466]]
[[    0.5452,    0.5308,    0.6999]]
[[    0.5452,    0.5308,    0.6999]]
[[    0.2480,    0.2490,    0.2101]]
```

Comparing against python's numpy:

```
>>> def sigmoid(x):
...     return 1.0 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
... 
>>> def sigmoid_derivative(x):
...     a = sigmoid(x)
...     return a * (1.0 - a)

>>> x = np.array([    0.1812,    0.1235,    0.8466])
>>> sigmoid(x)
array([0.54517646, 0.53083582, 0.69985343])
>>> sigmoid_derivative(x)
array([0.24795909, 0.24904915, 0.21005861])
```

Nd4j pom:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0-beta3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: FYI: Your implementation of `sigmoid_derivative(x)` is not correct.  It should be `y = sigmoid(x); return y*(1 - y)`

Comment: Something is wrong with your nd4j code, too.  The third row of the output, which is supposed to be `sigmoidDerivative(x)`, is the same as the second row, which is `sigmoid(x)`.

Comment: Facepalm! @WarrenWeckesser you are right my python implementation is wrong.

Comment: Correcting my python code to : `>>> def sigmoid_derivative(x):
...     a=sigmoid(x)
...     return a * (1.0 - a)
`

gives output: `array([0.24795909, 0.24904915, 0.21005861])`

Comment: Actually changing `System.out.println(Transforms.sigmoidDerivative(x));` to `System.out.println(Transforms.sigmoidDerivative(x, true));` gives the expected sigmoid derivative `[[    0.2480,    0.2490,    0.2101]]` Thanks solved! Editing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, both `Transforms.sigmoidDerivative(x)` and `Transforms.sigmoidDerivative(x, true)` should give the same results, it's a bug in dl4j. The correct behavior has the latter method. I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/pull/7037) to resolve it.